# Using required namespace in the repl

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

When I require a namespace inside a clojure-script source file, I can use it afterwards in the code.

E.g:

```
(ns my.core
  (:require [mylib.core :as lib]))

(lib/my-f)

(def something 99)
```

However, when I try to call `(lib/my-f)` inside the repl - after changing the namespace via `(ns my.core)` - I cannot access it. In contrast, all other definitions inside the ns are acessible: like `something` from the example above.

Is there a way to access the requirements in the repl? Or do I have to require them manually in the repl every time? This would be very tedious of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `ns` to change namespace in a ClojureScript REPL, this sets the namespace aliases to match those used in the `ns` form.

Here is an example illustrating the concept:

```
$ clj -m cljs.main
ClojureScript 1.10.520
cljs.user=> (ns foo.core (:require [clojure.string :as string]))

foo.core=> (string/starts-with? "abc" "a")
true
foo.core=> (ns bar.core)

bar.core=> (ns foo.core)

foo.core=> (string/starts-with? "abc" "a")
WARNING: No such namespace: string, could not locate string.cljs, string.cljc, or Closure namespace "" at line 1 <cljs repl>
WARNING: Use of undeclared Var string/starts-with? at line 1 <cljs repl>
ReferenceError: "string" is not defined
```

If instead you use the `in-ns` REPL special to change to an existing namespace, this will preserve aliases:

```
$ clj -m cljs.main
ClojureScript 1.10.520
cljs.user=> (ns foo.core (:require [clojure.string :as string]))

foo.core=> (string/starts-with? "abc" "a")
true
foo.core=> (ns bar.core)

bar.core=> (in-ns 'foo.core)
nil
foo.core=> (string/starts-with? "abc" "a")
true
```

An interesting related aspect: If you use `require`, it will, under the hoods, employ an `ns` form with special meta baked into the form that preserves existing aliases:

```
$ clj -m cljs.main
ClojureScript 1.10.520
cljs.user=> (require '[clojure.string :as string])
nil
cljs.user=> (require '[clojure.string :as str])
nil
cljs.user=> (string/starts-with? "abc" "a")
true
cljs.user=> (str/starts-with? "abc" "a")
true
```

If you are curious, this is the `:merge true` meta here: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r1.7.228/src/main/clojure/cljs/repl.cljc#L679

and it is honored by the analyzer here: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r1.7.228/src/main/clojure/cljs/analyzer.cljc#L1953

By seeing how this works, it should provide some insight into why an `ns` form evaluated directly in the REPL (without `merge` meta) can lead to aliases being cleared.

In short, avoid directly using the `ns` special to change to a namespace in the REPL. Instead use it to create a new namespace in the REPL while specifying any required namespaces.

Use the `in-ns` REPL special to switch to an existing namespace. It can also be used to create a new namespace.

Use `require` to load namespaces into the REPL, and then use `in-ns` to switch to them.

Comment: thanks for the long answer. in-ns was the magic I was looking for. saves me a lot of typing now..

Answer (score 1):

As long as you `require` the namespace before switching to it with `ns` or `in-ns`, this all should work fine. The puzzling thing to me is that `something` is accessible, meaning your code was loaded: that should mean that its namespace form was evaluated too, and thus you should have its aliases available. Are you sure you did this from a fresh state, and didn't, say, define `something` independently as well? Double-check by:

1. Close the repl
2. Start a new repl
3. `(require 'my.core)`
4. `(in-ns 'my.core)`
5. Check that the stuff in your question is still true. Can you still access `something?` Can you still *not* access `lib/my-f`? I predict that one of those two things will change: you should be able to access neither, or both.

Comment: check out my question again: I used ns istead of in-ns - that was my mistake. thank you anyways! To me it looks now, that the third point of your list is not necessary. just using (in-ns '..) does all the requiring already.

Comment: @AntonHarald `in-ns` does not load code. It switches the REPL's namespace (and creates it if needed). So in your case, the `my.core` namespace was already loaded before you evaluated `(ns my.core)`.